# How to get extensionContext in vscode extension unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently I am writing unit tests about vscode extension. But some functions are using extensionContext and I can't get extensionContext in unit tests. Any way to get it?

Answer (score 6):

Just came across this question, because I had exactly the same problem.

It looks like you can do the following in a test:

```js
const ext = vscode.extensions.getExtension("publisher.extensionName");
```

And you can return anything from your activate function, so you could decide to return the extension context (or anything else that you need) there:

```js
export async function activate(
  context: vscode.ExtensionContext
): Promise<vscode.ExtensionContext> {
  // Your activation code...

  return context;
}
```

And then you can access the context in the test:

```js
const ext = vscode.extensions.getExtension("publisher.extensionName");
const myExtensionContext = await ext.activate();
```

You find `publisher.extensionName` information in `package.json` of the extension:

```
{
    "publisher": "myself",
    "name": "myextension",
    "displayName": "My Extension",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to add a command that returns the context:

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('getContext', () => context));
}
```

and then get the context by:

```js
const context = await vscode.commands.executeCommand("getContext") as vscode.ExtensionContext;
```

**But be careful not to expose the context in production**

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to an old question, but I've had the same problem and I'm answering it now, so others can see it.

I found this solution in https://github.dev/microsoft/vscode extensions/vscode-api-test/src/extension.ts and extensions/vscode-api-test/src/singlefolder-test/state.test.ts files.

First, the context entered in the activate function must be registered in the global as shown below.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(_context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // Set context as a global as some tests depend on it
    (global as any).testExtensionContext = _context;
}
```

After that, you can use it as follows in the file to be tested.

```
import * as assert from 'assert';
import 'mocha';
import { ExtensionContext, extensions } from 'vscode';

suite('vscode API - globalState / workspaceState', () => {

    let extensionContext: ExtensionContext;
    suiteSetup(async () => {
        // Trigger extension activation and grab the context as some tests depend on it
        await extensions.getExtension('vscode.vscode-api-tests')?.activate();
        extensionContext = (global as any).testExtensionContext;
    });

    test('state', async () => {
        // Do some tests here using extensionContext
        }
    });
});
```

In the signature of the activate function, context is received as a parameter, but I don't know why, but here it can be used without setting context as a parameter. It may be that the corresponding value is entered automatically.