# How to share VS Code extension context across extension's modules?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS Code extension using Javascript instead of Typescript. That said, I want to be able to use my extension's context across various modules without having to pass it as an explicit argument to each function in my modules (which is what I'm currently doing... the problem is I have a seeming Russian Doll situation of passing the context to a function that calls another function that calls another function which is the only function that needs the context).

My current approach relies on returning the context from the main `activate()` function [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036883/how-to-get-extensioncontext-in-vscode-extension-unit-test). But this seems like **bad practice** since I'd be exposing my context to other extensions which could then access sensitive information stored via secrets API, as [emphasized here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669712/3491991).

So how can we just load the context on a module or intra-function basis? Any code samples I find that seem to accomplish this all use Typescript (like [this sample](https://dev.to/kompotkot/how-to-use-secretstorage-in-your-vscode-extensions-2hco), or [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/blob/611d819b535b98c0066d0ef7e42e32bcb2a2b24d/src/github/credentials.ts#L40) ) which I can't get to work in my project.